# Ubuntu 19.04 Boot time very long

Tags: boot, boot-time

I'm wondering what is wrong with my Ubuntu boot time.
I have a recent computer, with a Windows dual boot (i5 8th gen)
What does userspace part refer to ?

```
olivbau@olivier-Ubuntu:~$ systemd-analyze blame 
      6.405s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      5.207s fwupd.service
      5.037s bolt.service
      2.824s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      1.084s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
      1.032s plymouth-read-write.service
       783ms snapd.service
       720ms dev-nvme0n1p5.device
       627ms systemd-logind.service
       566ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1198.mount
       563ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-254.mount
       546ms snap-docker-384.mount
       517ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-31.mount
       496ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-77.mount
       476ms snap-code-8.mount
       448ms snap-core-6673.mount
       425ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-61.mount
       416ms snap-core18-941.mount
       382ms systemd-journald.service
       372ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-406.mount
       363ms snap-insomnia-30.mount
       354ms dev-loop3.device
       340ms dev-loop1.device
olivbau@olivier-Ubuntu:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 37.011s
└─multi-user.target @1min 37.011s
  └─kerneloops.service @1min 37.001s +10ms
    └─network-online.target @1min 36.995s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 30.589s +6.405s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1min 30.509s +75ms
          └─dbus.service @1min 30.494s
            └─basic.target @1min 30.479s
              └─sockets.target @1min 30.479s
                └─snapd.socket @1min 30.477s +1ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1min 30.470s
                    └─systemd-    backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service @790ms +1.084s
                  └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @789ms
                    └─system.slice @221ms
                      └─-.slice @221ms
```

```
olivbau@olivier-Ubuntu:~$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 6.867s (firmware) + 4.795s (loader) + 2.567s (kernel) + 3min 720ms (userspace) = 3min 14.951s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 37.011s in userspace
```

[SVG plot](https://svgshare.com/i/D_H.svg)

edit:

```
 olivbau@olivier-Ubuntu:~$ lsblk | grep -v 'loop'
 NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
 sda           8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
 └─sda1        8:1    0 638,6G  0 part 
 nvme0n1     259:0    0 119,2G  0 disk 
 ├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   529M  0 part 
 ├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
 ├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0    16M  0 part 
 ├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0  86,4G  0 part 
 └─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0  32,2G  0 part /
```

Comment: so the windows boots faster? what's the laptop part number? what is the disk setup? what' your ouput for : `lsblk | grep -v 'loop`?

Comment: Windows boots in less than 10sec.